# Cambiar caracteres de un fichero por espacios en blanco en Java

Tags: java

estoy empezando a programar (solo llevo mes y medio) y me ha tocado comenzar con Java. La cuestión es que tengo que realizar dentro de un programa un método que, al leer un fichero en el que hay muchos tweets, cambie diversos caracteres poco comunes que aparezcan (+ ^ * por ejemplo) por espacios en blanco y que esto lo almacene en un fichero de salida por medio del parámetro "output". Esto es lo que tengo por ahora (sé que hay cosas que están mal), pero estoy totalmente atascado ¿Algún héroe anónimo que me pueda ayudar?

```
public static void filtroContenido(String input, String output) {
   char validos [] = {',' , '.' , ';' , ':' , ' ' , '_' , '-' , '#' , '@' , '/'};

try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileReader entrada = new FileReader(input);
        PrintWriter Tweets_Filtrados = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("Tweets_Filtrados"));
        int Tweets_Leidos = entrada.read();
            
            
        while(sc.hasNext()); {
            Tweets_Leidos = entrada.read();
            char Tweet = (char)Tweets_Leidos; // para convertir 0 y 1 en letras
            entrada.write(input);
                
            output = input.replaceAll(validos, " ");
                
            
                
            }
            
            entrada.close();
        }
catch(java.io.IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + ioex);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Seguro que podemos ayudarte!!! que intentaste? donde esta el codigo de tu programa? en que parte no pudiste???

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener los caracteres que deseas eliminar en una lista o cualquier estructura de datos que prefieras, para posteriormente leer el archivo y recorrer la linea leída (almacenando el texto también), en caso que el carácter este en esa estructura que elegiste que lo cambie y al finalizar de leer todo el archivo reescriba el mismo, es una solucion muy poco optima ya que almacenas demasiado en memoria, puedes usar funciones como fseek, en java también existen, para almacenar el byte en donde esta ese carácter y así solo sobrescribir el mismo